# Filter context for should query in elasricsearch?

Tags: python, elasticsearch, elasticsearch-5

I have a must query which looks like this:

```
{
    "query": {
        "bool": {
            "must": [{
                "match": {
                    "section": {
                        "query": "word1",
                        "boost": "3"
                    }
                }
            }, {
                "match": {
                    "section": {
                        "query": "word2",
                        "boost": "4"
                    }
                }
            }]
        }
    }
}
```

How can I make it "OR" i.e. All the documents which match "word1", "word2" or both, because the above code gives me results in the documents which contain both "word1" and "word2".

I read in the [documentation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-filter-context.html) that this can be achieved by using should in the filter context but I couldn't find any example.

Thanks

Comment: Simply replace `must` by `should` and you'll get what you expect.

Answer (score 0):

You should use `should` block instead of `must`. Here is a correct query

```
{
    "query": {
        "bool": {
            "should": [
                {
                    "match": {
                        "section": {
                            "query": "word1",
                            "boost": "3"
                        }
                    }
                },
                {
                    "match": {
                        "section": {
                            "query": "word2",
                            "boost": "4"
                        }
                    }
                }
            ]
        }
    }
}
```

As for the `filter` block, it will return the same documents as `must` but won't affect the final score

Comment: And set a `minmum_should_match: 1` to match at least in one case.

Comment: It's not necessary if there are no `must` and `filter` conditions